# Find the most general bilinear transformation that maps $|z-1|=1$ to $\Re(f(z)) = 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Find the most general bilinear transformation that maps $|z-1|=1$ to $\Re(f(z)) = 1$.

**Attempt**

Assuming that
$$
2 \mapsto 1 \\
0 \mapsto \infty \\
1+i \mapsto 1+i
$$
we have the bilinear transformation 
$$
f(z) = 2 \left( \frac{z-1}{z} \right).
$$
But how do we find the form of ***all*** such mappings? My only guess is to compose $f$ with a $g$ that always maps $\Re(w)$ to itself. I would think that 
$$
T(z) = (g \circ f)(z) = 2 \left( \frac{z-1}{z} \right) + i\alpha,
   \quad \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
$$ 
gives the *most general* form of all such transformations. But how can I prove to myself that this is right (if it is)?

Comment: Why do you use the term "bilinear transformation"? What two variables is your transformation linear with respect to?

I'm assuming you mean bijection or biholomorphism.

Comment: @Mark mobius transformations are also sometimes referred to as bilinear transformations.